# Why is the jquery script not working if I add a new element?

Tags: javascript, jquery

why is the jQuery script not working if I add an extra element?

The script works fine with 25 of the blocks. One more and the script does not work anymore.

Please take a look at the script below and add a new block.

```js
$('.halfblock').each(function(index, element){
      $('.openlink').on('click', function(event) {
          event.preventDefault();
          var text = $(this).text();
          $(this).parent().parent().parent().toggleClass('opened');
          $(this).text(text == "schließen" ? "Weitere Infos" : "schließen");
      });
    });
```

```css
.halfblock .fulltext{
  display: none;
  font-size: 14px !important;
  margin-top: 20px;
  color: #222222 !important;
}

.halfblock.opened .fulltext{
  display: block;
}

.openfull{
  background: #111;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="halfblock">
<div class="text">
    <h3>1</h3>
    <p class="previewtext">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam</p>
    <p class="fulltext">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam.</p>
    <p class="openfull"><span class="openlink">Weitere Infos</span></p>
</div>
</div>

<div class="halfblock">
<div class="text">
    <h3>2</h3>
    <p class="previewtext">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam</p>
    <p class="fulltext">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam.</p>
    <p class="openfull"><span class="openlink">Weitere Infos</span></p>
</div>
</div>

<div class="halfblock">
<div class="text">
    <h3>3</h3>
    <p class="previewtext">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam</p>
    <p class="fulltext">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam.</p>
    <p class="openfull"><span class="openlink">Weitere Infos</span></p>
</div>
</div>

<div class="halfblock">
<div class="text">
    <h3>4</h3>
    <p class="previewtext">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam</p>
    <p class="fulltext">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam.</p>
    <p class="openfull"><span class="openlink">Weitere Infos</span></p>
</div>
</div>

<div class="halfblock">
<div class="text">
    <h3>5</h3>
    <p class="previewtext">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam</p>
    <p class="fulltext">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam.</p>
    <p class="openfull"><span class="openlink">Weitere Infos</span></p>
</div>
</div>

<div class="halfblock">
<div class="text">
    <h3>6</h3>
    <p class="previewtext">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam</p>
    <p class="fulltext">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam.</p>
    <p class="openfull"><span class="openlink">Weitere Infos</span></p>
</div>
</div>

<div class="halfblock">
<div class="text">
    <h3>7</h3>
    <p class="previewtext">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam</p>
    <p class="fulltext">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam.</p>
    <p class="openfull"><span class="openlink">Weitere Infos</span></p>
</div>
</div>

<div class="halfblock">
<div class="text">
    <h3>8</h3>
    <p class="previewtext">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam</p>
    <p class="fulltext">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam.</p>
    <p class="openfull"><span class="openlink">Weitere Infos</span></p>
</div>
</div>

<div class="halfblock">
<div class="text">
    <h3>9</h3>
    <p class="previewtext">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam</p>
    <p class="fulltext">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam.</p>
    <p class="openfull"><span class="openlink">Weitere Infos</span></p>
</div>
</div>

<div class="halfblock">
<div class="text">
    <h3>10</h3>
    <p class="previewtext">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam</p>
    <p class="fulltext">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam.</p>
    <p class="openfull"><span class="openlink">Weitere Infos</span></p>
</div>
</div>

<div class="halfblock">
<div class="text">
    <h3>11</h3>
    <p class="previewtext">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam</p>
    <p class="fulltext">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam.</p>
    <p class="openfull"><span class="openlink">Weitere Infos</span></p>
</div>
</div>

<div class="halfblock">
<div class="text">
    <h3>12</h3>
    <p class="previewtext">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam</p>
    <p class="fulltext">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam.</p>
    <p class="openfull"><span class="openlink">Weitere Infos</span></p>
</div>
</div>

<div class="halfblock">
<div class="text">
    <h3>13</h3>
    <p class="previewtext">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam</p>
    <p class="fulltext">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam.</p>
    <p class="openfull"><span class="openlink">Weitere Infos</span></p>
</div>
</div>

<div class="halfblock">
<div class="text">
    <h3>14</h3>
    <p class="previewtext">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam</p>
    <p class="fulltext">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam.</p>
    <p class="openfull"><span class="openlink">Weitere Infos</span></p>
</div>
</div>

<div class="halfblock">
<div class="text">
    <h3>15</h3>
    <p class="previewtext">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam</p>
    <p class="fulltext">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam.</p>
    <p class="openfull"><span class="openlink">Weitere Infos</span></p>
</div>
</div>

<div class="halfblock">
<div class="text">
    <h3>16</h3>
    <p class="previewtext">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam</p>
    <p class="fulltext">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam.</p>
    <p class="openfull"><span class="openlink">Weitere Infos</span></p>
</div>
</div>

<div class="halfblock">
<div class="text">
    <h3>17</h3>
    <p class="previewtext">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam</p>
    <p class="fulltext">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam.</p>
    <p class="openfull"><span class="openlink">Weitere Infos</span></p>
</div>
</div>

<div class="halfblock">
<div class="text">
    <h3>18</h3>
    <p class="previewtext">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam</p>
    <p class="fulltext">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam.</p>
    <p class="openfull"><span class="openlink">Weitere Infos</span></p>
</div>
</div>

<div class="halfblock">
<div class="text">
    <h3>19</h3>
    <p class="previewtext">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam</p>
    <p class="fulltext">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam.</p>
    <p class="openfull"><span class="openlink">Weitere Infos</span></p>
</div>
</div>

<div class="halfblock">
<div class="text">
    <h3>20</h3>
    <p class="previewtext">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam</p>
    <p class="fulltext">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam.</p>
    <p class="openfull"><span class="openlink">Weitere Infos</span></p>
</div>
</div>

<div class="halfblock">
<div class="text">
    <h3>21</h3>
    <p class="previewtext">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam</p>
    <p class="fulltext">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam.</p>
    <p class="openfull"><span class="openlink">Weitere Infos</span></p>
</div>
</div>

<div class="halfblock">
<div class="text">
    <h3>22</h3>
    <p class="previewtext">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam</p>
    <p class="fulltext">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam.</p>
    <p class="openfull"><span class="openlink">Weitere Infos</span></p>
</div>
</div>

<div class="halfblock">
<div class="text">
    <h3>23</h3>
    <p class="previewtext">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam</p>
    <p class="fulltext">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam.</p>
    <p class="openfull"><span class="openlink">Weitere Infos</span></p>
</div>
</div>

<div class="halfblock">
<div class="text">
    <h3>24</h3>
    <p class="previewtext">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam</p>
    <p class="fulltext">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam.</p>
    <p class="openfull"><span class="openlink">Weitere Infos</span></p>
</div>
</div>

<div class="halfblock">
<div class="text">
    <h3>25</h3>
    <p class="previewtext">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam</p>
    <p class="fulltext">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam.</p>
    <p class="openfull"><span class="openlink">Weitere Infos</span></p>
</div>
</div>

<div class="halfblock">
<div class="text">
    <h3>26</h3>
    <p class="previewtext">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam</p>
    <p class="fulltext">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam.</p>
    <p class="openfull"><span class="openlink">Weitere Infos</span></p>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: its working. what's the issue?

Answer (score 1):

You’re adding the event listener for every instance of `.halfblock`. For an odd number of elements like 25, the first 24 will cancel each other out and you’ll be left with the intended effect of one toggle; for an even number like 26, they’ll all cancel out and nothing will happen.

Just add the listener once, without the `.each`:

```
$('.openlink').on('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var text = $(this).text();
    $(this).parent().parent().parent().toggleClass('opened');
    $(this).text(text == "schließen" ? "Weitere Infos" : "schließen");
});
```

You might also find `.closest('.halfblock')` more readable than `.parent().parent().parent()`.

```js
$('.openlink').on('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var text = $(this).text();
    $(this).closest('.halfblock').toggleClass('opened');
    $(this).text(text == "schließen" ? "Weitere Infos" : "schließen");
});
```

```css
.halfblock .fulltext{
  display: none;
  font-size: 14px !important;
  margin-top: 20px;
  color: #222222 !important;
}

.halfblock.opened .fulltext{
  display: block;
}

.openfull{
  background: #111;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="halfblock">
<div class="text">
    <h3>1</h3>
    <p class="previewtext">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam</p>
    <p class="fulltext">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam.</p>
    <p class="openfull"><span class="openlink">Weitere Infos</span></p>
</div>
</div>

<div class="halfblock">
<div class="text">
    <h3>2</h3>
    <p class="previewtext">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam</p>
    <p class="fulltext">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam.</p>
    <p class="openfull"><span class="openlink">Weitere Infos</span></p>
</div>
</div>

<div class="halfblock">
<div class="text">
    <h3>3</h3>
    <p class="previewtext">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam</p>
    <p class="fulltext">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam.</p>
    <p class="openfull"><span class="openlink">Weitere Infos</span></p>
</div>
</div>

<div class="halfblock">
<div class="text">
    <h3>4</h3>
    <p class="previewtext">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam</p>
    <p class="fulltext">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam.</p>
    <p class="openfull"><span class="openlink">Weitere Infos</span></p>
</div>
</div>

<div class="halfblock">
<div class="text">
    <h3>5</h3>
    <p class="previewtext">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam</p>
    <p class="fulltext">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam.</p>
    <p class="openfull"><span class="openlink">Weitere Infos</span></p>
</div>
</div>

<div class="halfblock">
<div class="text">
    <h3>6</h3>
    <p class="previewtext">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam</p>
    <p class="fulltext">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam.</p>
    <p class="openfull"><span class="openlink">Weitere Infos</span></p>
</div>
</div>

<div class="halfblock">
<div class="text">
    <h3>7</h3>
    <p class="previewtext">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam</p>
    <p class="fulltext">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam.</p>
    <p class="openfull"><span class="openlink">Weitere Infos</span></p>
</div>
</div>

<div class="halfblock">
<div class="text">
    <h3>8</h3>
    <p class="previewtext">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam</p>
    <p class="fulltext">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam.</p>
    <p class="openfull"><span class="openlink">Weitere Infos</span></p>
</div>
</div>

<div class="halfblock">
<div class="text">
    <h3>9</h3>
    <p class="previewtext">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam</p>
    <p class="fulltext">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam.</p>
    <p class="openfull"><span class="openlink">Weitere Infos</span></p>
</div>
</div>

<div class="halfblock">
<div class="text">
    <h3>10</h3>
    <p class="previewtext">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam</p>
    <p class="fulltext">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam.</p>
    <p class="openfull"><span class="openlink">Weitere Infos</span></p>
</div>
</div>

<div class="halfblock">
<div class="text">
    <h3>11</h3>
    <p class="previewtext">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam</p>
    <p class="fulltext">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam.</p>
    <p class="openfull"><span class="openlink">Weitere Infos</span></p>
</div>
</div>

<div class="halfblock">
<div class="text">
    <h3>12</h3>
    <p class="previewtext">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam</p>
    <p class="fulltext">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam.</p>
    <p class="openfull"><span class="openlink">Weitere Infos</span></p>
</div>
</div>

<div class="halfblock">
<div class="text">
    <h3>13</h3>
    <p class="previewtext">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam</p>
    <p class="fulltext">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam.</p>
    <p class="openfull"><span class="openlink">Weitere Infos</span></p>
</div>
</div>

<div class="halfblock">
<div class="text">
    <h3>14</h3>
    <p class="previewtext">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam</p>
    <p class="fulltext">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam.</p>
    <p class="openfull"><span class="openlink">Weitere Infos</span></p>
</div>
</div>

<div class="halfblock">
<div class="text">
    <h3>15</h3>
    <p class="previewtext">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam</p>
    <p class="fulltext">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam.</p>
    <p class="openfull"><span class="openlink">Weitere Infos</span></p>
</div>
</div>

<div class="halfblock">
<div class="text">
    <h3>16</h3>
    <p class="previewtext">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam</p>
    <p class="fulltext">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam.</p>
    <p class="openfull"><span class="openlink">Weitere Infos</span></p>
</div>
</div>

<div class="halfblock">
<div class="text">
    <h3>17</h3>
    <p class="previewtext">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam</p>
    <p class="fulltext">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam.</p>
    <p class="openfull"><span class="openlink">Weitere Infos</span></p>
</div>
</div>

<div class="halfblock">
<div class="text">
    <h3>18</h3>
    <p class="previewtext">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam</p>
    <p class="fulltext">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam.</p>
    <p class="openfull"><span class="openlink">Weitere Infos</span></p>
</div>
</div>

<div class="halfblock">
<div class="text">
    <h3>19</h3>
    <p class="previewtext">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam</p>
    <p class="fulltext">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam.</p>
    <p class="openfull"><span class="openlink">Weitere Infos</span></p>
</div>
</div>

<div class="halfblock">
<div class="text">
    <h3>20</h3>
    <p class="previewtext">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam</p>
    <p class="fulltext">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam.</p>
    <p class="openfull"><span class="openlink">Weitere Infos</span></p>
</div>
</div>

<div class="halfblock">
<div class="text">
    <h3>21</h3>
    <p class="previewtext">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam</p>
    <p class="fulltext">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam.</p>
    <p class="openfull"><span class="openlink">Weitere Infos</span></p>
</div>
</div>

<div class="halfblock">
<div class="text">
    <h3>22</h3>
    <p class="previewtext">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam</p>
    <p class="fulltext">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam.</p>
    <p class="openfull"><span class="openlink">Weitere Infos</span></p>
</div>
</div>

<div class="halfblock">
<div class="text">
    <h3>23</h3>
    <p class="previewtext">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam</p>
    <p class="fulltext">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam.</p>
    <p class="openfull"><span class="openlink">Weitere Infos</span></p>
</div>
</div>

<div class="halfblock">
<div class="text">
    <h3>24</h3>
    <p class="previewtext">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam</p>
    <p class="fulltext">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam.</p>
    <p class="openfull"><span class="openlink">Weitere Infos</span></p>
</div>
</div>

<div class="halfblock">
<div class="text">
    <h3>25</h3>
    <p class="previewtext">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam</p>
    <p class="fulltext">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam.</p>
    <p class="openfull"><span class="openlink">Weitere Infos</span></p>
</div>
</div>

<div class="halfblock">
<div class="text">
    <h3>26</h3>
    <p class="previewtext">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam</p>
    <p class="fulltext">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam.</p>
    <p class="openfull"><span class="openlink">Weitere Infos</span></p>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `.each()` on event, use only selector for events:

```js
$('.halfblock .openlink').on('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var text = $(this).text();
    $(this).parent().parent().parent().toggleClass('opened');
    $(this).text(text == "schließen" ? "Weitere Infos" : "schließen");
});
```

```css
.halfblock .fulltext{
  display: none;
  font-size: 14px !important;
  margin-top: 20px;
  color: #222222 !important;
}

.halfblock.opened .fulltext{
  display: block;
}

.openfull{
  background: #111;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="halfblock">
<div class="text">
    <h3>1</h3>
    <p class="previewtext">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam</p>
    <p class="fulltext">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam.</p>
    <p class="openfull"><span class="openlink">Weitere Infos</span></p>
</div>
</div>

<div class="halfblock">
<div class="text">
    <h3>2</h3>
    <p class="previewtext">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam</p>
    <p class="fulltext">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam.</p>
    <p class="openfull"><span class="openlink">Weitere Infos</span></p>
</div>
</div>

<div class="halfblock">
<div class="text">
    <h3>3</h3>
    <p class="previewtext">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam</p>
    <p class="fulltext">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam.</p>
    <p class="openfull"><span class="openlink">Weitere Infos</span></p>
</div>
</div>

<div class="halfblock">
<div class="text">
    <h3>4</h3>
    <p class="previewtext">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam</p>
    <p class="fulltext">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam.</p>
    <p class="openfull"><span class="openlink">Weitere Infos</span></p>
</div>
</div>

<div class="halfblock">
<div class="text">
    <h3>5</h3>
    <p class="previewtext">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam</p>
    <p class="fulltext">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam.</p>
    <p class="openfull"><span class="openlink">Weitere Infos</span></p>
</div>
</div>

<div class="halfblock">
<div class="text">
    <h3>6</h3>
    <p class="previewtext">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam</p>
    <p class="fulltext">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam.</p>
    <p class="openfull"><span class="openlink">Weitere Infos</span></p>
</div>
</div>

<div class="halfblock">
<div class="text">
    <h3>7</h3>
    <p class="previewtext">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam</p>
    <p class="fulltext">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam.</p>
    <p class="openfull"><span class="openlink">Weitere Infos</span></p>
</div>
</div>

<div class="halfblock">
<div class="text">
    <h3>8</h3>
    <p class="previewtext">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam</p>
    <p class="fulltext">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam.</p>
    <p class="openfull"><span class="openlink">Weitere Infos</span></p>
</div>
</div>

<div class="halfblock">
<div class="text">
    <h3>9</h3>
    <p class="previewtext">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam</p>
    <p class="fulltext">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam.</p>
    <p class="openfull"><span class="openlink">Weitere Infos</span></p>
</div>
</div>

<div class="halfblock">
<div class="text">
    <h3>10</h3>
    <p class="previewtext">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam</p>
    <p class="fulltext">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam.</p>
    <p class="openfull"><span class="openlink">Weitere Infos</span></p>
</div>
</div>

<div class="halfblock">
<div class="text">
    <h3>11</h3>
    <p class="previewtext">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam</p>
    <p class="fulltext">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam.</p>
    <p class="openfull"><span class="openlink">Weitere Infos</span></p>
</div>
</div>

<div class="halfblock">
<div class="text">
    <h3>12</h3>
    <p class="previewtext">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam</p>
    <p class="fulltext">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam.</p>
    <p class="openfull"><span class="openlink">Weitere Infos</span></p>
</div>
</div>

<div class="halfblock">
<div class="text">
    <h3>13</h3>
    <p class="previewtext">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam</p>
    <p class="fulltext">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam.</p>
    <p class="openfull"><span class="openlink">Weitere Infos</span></p>
</div>
</div>

<div class="halfblock">
<div class="text">
    <h3>14</h3>
    <p class="previewtext">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam</p>
    <p class="fulltext">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam.</p>
    <p class="openfull"><span class="openlink">Weitere Infos</span></p>
</div>
</div>

<div class="halfblock">
<div class="text">
    <h3>15</h3>
    <p class="previewtext">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam</p>
    <p class="fulltext">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam.</p>
    <p class="openfull"><span class="openlink">Weitere Infos</span></p>
</div>
</div>

<div class="halfblock">
<div class="text">
    <h3>16</h3>
    <p class="previewtext">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam</p>
    <p class="fulltext">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam.</p>
    <p class="openfull"><span class="openlink">Weitere Infos</span></p>
</div>
</div>

<div class="halfblock">
<div class="text">
    <h3>17</h3>
    <p class="previewtext">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam</p>
    <p class="fulltext">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam.</p>
    <p class="openfull"><span class="openlink">Weitere Infos</span></p>
</div>
</div>

<div class="halfblock">
<div class="text">
    <h3>18</h3>
    <p class="previewtext">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam</p>
    <p class="fulltext">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam.</p>
    <p class="openfull"><span class="openlink">Weitere Infos</span></p>
</div>
</div>

<div class="halfblock">
<div class="text">
    <h3>19</h3>
    <p class="previewtext">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam</p>
    <p class="fulltext">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam.</p>
    <p class="openfull"><span class="openlink">Weitere Infos</span></p>
</div>
</div>

<div class="halfblock">
<div class="text">
    <h3>20</h3>
    <p class="previewtext">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam</p>
    <p class="fulltext">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam.</p>
    <p class="openfull"><span class="openlink">Weitere Infos</span></p>
</div>
</div>

<div class="halfblock">
<div class="text">
    <h3>21</h3>
    <p class="previewtext">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam</p>
    <p class="fulltext">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam.</p>
    <p class="openfull"><span class="openlink">Weitere Infos</span></p>
</div>
</div>

<div class="halfblock">
<div class="text">
    <h3>22</h3>
    <p class="previewtext">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam</p>
    <p class="fulltext">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam.</p>
    <p class="openfull"><span class="openlink">Weitere Infos</span></p>
</div>
</div>

<div class="halfblock">
<div class="text">
    <h3>23</h3>
    <p class="previewtext">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam</p>
    <p class="fulltext">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam.</p>
    <p class="openfull"><span class="openlink">Weitere Infos</span></p>
</div>
</div>

<div class="halfblock">
<div class="text">
    <h3>24</h3>
    <p class="previewtext">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam</p>
    <p class="fulltext">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam.</p>
    <p class="openfull"><span class="openlink">Weitere Infos</span></p>
</div>
</div>

<div class="halfblock">
<div class="text">
    <h3>25</h3>
    <p class="previewtext">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam</p>
    <p class="fulltext">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam.</p>
    <p class="openfull"><span class="openlink">Weitere Infos</span></p>
</div>
</div>

<div class="halfblock">
<div class="text">
    <h3>26</h3>
    <p class="previewtext">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam</p>
    <p class="fulltext">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam.</p>
    <p class="openfull"><span class="openlink">Weitere Infos</span></p>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your script is equal to this

```
`$('.openlink').on('click', function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      var text = $(this).text();
      $(this).parent().parent().parent().toggleClass('opened');
      $(this).text(text == "schließen" ? "Weitere Infos" : "schließen");
  });`
```

Why did you write each function? When I write this script with your html it is working fine